# jquery toggle how to use for individual elements without individual id's?

Tags: jquery, html, toggleclass

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>FAQ Section</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h2").click(function(){
    $("p").toggle("fast");
  });
}); </script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>FAQ</h1>

  <div> 
    <!-- The FAQs are inserted here -->

      <h2>Question1?</h2>
      <p>Answer...</p>
      <h2>Question2?</h2>
      <p>Answer...</p>
      <h2>Question3?</h2>
      <p>Answer...</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is my sample page : http://www.kursatkarabulut.com/kopya.html

What I'm trying to do is a FAQ page for my personal site. There will be around 40 questions. I'm new to jQuery. I used toggle for each question. Only questions will show on start and when the user clicks on a question, it'll display below, click again and it'll hide. Right now when I click on a question it expands and contracts all questions.

Is there a way to do this individually without using individual id's for each heading?
And how can load a page with toggle off?

Thanks.

Comment: you can do it but it would be easier to restructure the code a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this...

```
  $("h2").click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle("fast");
  });
```

and this will make the toggle on page load:

```
  $("h2").click();
```

or if you dont want the toggle animation on page load you can do this:

```
  $("p").toggle();
```

[See here for a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/GkpPn/)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("h2").click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h2").click(function(){
    $(this).next("p").toggle("fast");
  });
});
```